# Accessing AMI using Python/Flask to calculate call duration and limit

Tags: python, flask, asterisk

Hello Stackoverflowers,

Currently I am using Python to connect to AMI and everything is working fine. I can see live calls, hangup calls as well

But I have a task to accomplish, with every calls made I can see the duration of these calls. Now I have to deduct the duration from the balance added in the MySQL table column for the user.

So when (balance - current_duration) < 60seconds then an IVR should tell the user that he or she has 1 minute left.

Do you think this can be achieved using the Python/Flask script. Also the script will have to run asynchronously not needing to go to a page before the function can be activated.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use AMI interface. You will then have access to events for connection of call legs and for connection hangup. Also when needed you will be able to use AMI Redirect to transfer call to IVR (this will disconnect current call).

Flask is not good solution for this. It will be better to write own AMI client solution form scratch or use some libraries. Libraries may restrict your options. AMI protocol is easy to implement just text read/write on TCP socket (similar to HTTP).